# SQL syntax errors in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this code in `VB.Net` but I get the error `you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server to use near...`

How can I fix it?

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO isu_mod_alertare (nr_rap_ext_aler, mod, 
forte, procedee, cmd_fuct, nume_cmd) VALUES ('" + nrraport.Text + "', '"
+ MODT.Text + "', '" + fortet.Text + "', '" + procst.Text + "', '" 
+ cdtt.Text + "', '" + numecdt.Text + "')"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Are you able to print out the final content of `CommandText` somewhere? (E.g. if your code is in a console app, then to the console, if you're a forms app, then a message box, an asp.net app smuggle it into the next page's source, etc). Or even just put a breakpoint on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` and grab the text there.

Comment: Maybe there are some illegal characters in one of the textfields that destroy your SQL? You know that executing a query like this is dangerous (SQL injection)?

Comment: No are not illegal characters

Comment: Ok, please post the final SQL that is executed against the DB, as suggested by Damien.

Comment: WOW, worst command execution I've ever seen, it is ready for SQL Injection

Comment: If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
                    MsgBox("Raportul a fost adaugat")
                End If

Comment: So how can I prevent the sql injection?

Comment: You can use a parameterized query for instance.

Comment: http://tech.reboot.pro/showthread.php?tid=2732 - how to prevent sql injection using vb.net

Answer (score 0):

MOD is a reserved word in mysql so put a quote in your mod field like 'mod'

See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html)